# Parse "2023-12-12T00:00:00+05:30" in julia

Tags: julia

Please help in parsing the following:
`"2023-12-12T00:00:00+05:30"`

Currently I am using the following

```
function parsetime(dt::String)
    a,b=split(dt, '+')
    c,d=split(b,':')
    DateTime(a)+Hour(c)+Minute(d)
end
```

But, I think it is not very efficient. Please give some good methods.

Comment: Are you sure that "+05:30" means what you think it means? If you are trying to parse time arithmetic, then you are doing an okay job at it, but usually a "+" and a time at the end of a timestamp signifies a timezone. Check the [ISO 8601 standard for timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and see if it resolves your question.

Comment: @PaSTE might be an attempt to directly calculate UTC from this, except I think there should be subtraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using TimeZones
function parseZonedDateTime(dt::String)
    return ZonedDateTime(dt,"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSzzzz")
end

using Dates
function parseDateTime(dt::String)
    return DateTime(dt[1:(end-6)],"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS")
end

function parseToUTC(dt::ZonedDateTime)
    return astimezone(parseZonedDateTime(dt), tz"UTC")
end

# The best
function manualParseToUTC(dt::String)
    res = DateTime(dt[1:(end-6)],"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS")
    return res + Hour(parse(Int, x[(end-5):(end-3)]))
end
```